# Remote Control for windows 7 machines

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote, configuration-management

In the past (with windows XP) we have used the Altiris Deployment Console 6.9 SP3 to remote control our users machines. Since windows 7 has been released and deployed the remote control no longer works on windows 7. Symantec are not going to support this on the 6.9 X versions.
I am not going to go to version 7 (because it does not support PXE).
Does anyone know of any free/cheap solutions to remote control workstations runing windows 7 where you can see a list of devices and maybe even search for a username that is logged on to find that machine (nice to have but remote control with a list of machine names is enough)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used : http://www.dameware.com/products/dmrc/ and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some software I've used:
[Goverlan](http://www.pjtec.com/) : (Remote control, pushes the client) Good but not free.
[Uvnc](http://uvnc.com/) : (Freeware remote control)
[Lansweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com) : (Currently using this combined with uvnc/lansweeper remote control), I search the logged on user from the Lansweeper webinterface and launch the remote control to his computer.

Comment: Is the lansweeper/UVNC option free?
How do you find it?

Comment: Don't think so, we are using the premium version of Lansweeper.  With this you don't have to install the remote control software on the client, it pushes it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Vision App](http://www.visionapp.com/germany/solutions/asg-remote-desktop.html) for remote desktop organization and access.